# Let $G$ be a graph and $F$ a maximal forest of $G$. Show that $|E(F)| = |V(G)| - c(G)$.

Tags: graph-theory

I made a proof, but I'm not sure if it is correct, if anyone could help me, would be great.

Let $G$ be a graph and $F$ a maximal forest of $G$. Show that $|E(F)| = |V(G)| - c(G)$.

Proof.

We know that $F$ is a maximal forest of $G$, if $F$ is one set of spanning trees for every connected component of $G$.

Suppose $G$ is connected, so there is at least one spanning tree $F$ for $G$. Since $G$ es connected, $c(G) = 1$.

By the other hand, since $F$ is a tree, $F$ is a connected graph such that $|E(F)| = |V(G)| - 1$. Thus, $|E(F)| = |V(G)| - c(G)$.

If $G$ is not connected, we apply the same argument on every connected component of $G$.

Comment: Yes, that's fine ... on the basis of having the two little results used.

Comment: Which is the second result? That a tree $T$ is a connected graph such that $|E(T)| = n - 1$, and the other?

Comment: I counted also the existence of a spanning tree for a connected graph.